# Apps no longer install after 0.4.1 upgrade

Tags: appcenter

I installed updates (via App Center) to update to 0.4.1. This completed successfully but now I can't install any applications, including one I paid for. I get this error:

[image: Screenshot of error]

I don't recall changing any libcurl settings or anything that would cause this. Anyone have any ideas on how to resolve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you added the AppCenter repo when we were still in beta. You'll need to edit your apt sources list (`/etc/apt/sources.list`) to refer to `http` instead of `https`.

If you have `software-properties-common` you can do this with the following command:

`sudo add-apt-repository --remove 'deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.elementary.io/appcenter xenial main'`

Comment: Thanks Daniel, that pointed me in the right direction.I had been part of the AppCenter beta. The fix in the end was `sudo add-apt-repository --remove 'deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.elementary.io/appcenter xenial main'`